# How to scale image from center in windows phone app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I have this image:
[image: http://www.axgig.com/images/48616790538056722611.png]

I want to scale it in c# like this:
[image: http://www.axgig.com/images/86731759020234188511.png]

How can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create 4 Images out of it. It will then work the same way as it is done in responsive web UIs.
You have a fixed value for the width of the edges and the center and the remaining space is to be used for the image part which can be stretched horizontally left and right to the center image.

[image: New Version of your imag]

Image 1 will be used for the left side. Image 3 for the center and image 4 for the right part. Image 2 will be scaled between image 1 and 3 and also 3 and 4. Image 2 can be 1 px in width, as it does not change and you can strech it from 1 px to 100px without any loss of information compared to your original picture.